# i have to modify a wrong code. however im stuck on the part below and i'm getting this error in python

Tags: python

```
#this is a program to run on the HY92 module for the Nanya Rocket
print ("Program initiating")
date_today = "16 December 2016"
print (date_today)
print ('Mission Launch ' + 'Procedure 14.0')
module_name = "string(HY92)"
#the following are numerical variables
A1 = 4
A2 = 28
A3 = 10 #this is a module identifier
A4 = 14 #this is another module identifier
A5 = 39 
A6 = 6
#this is a section which uses the variables defined above
product = (A1 * A2)
quotient = (A4 / A3)
module_math = (product + quotient)
Clearance_Given = true
Clearance_Status = Clearance_given + module_math + module_name
sleep_time = 1
#print 'Program closing in...'
sleep(sleep_time)
print (5)
sleep(sleep_Time)
print (4)
sleep(sleep_time)
print (3)
sleep(sleep_time)
print (3)
sleep(sleep_time)
print (1)
sleep(sleep_time) 
print ("closed")
```

**i have made a lot of fixing however im stuck on the error which is showing on line 19 telling me that i can only concatenate str (not float ) to str**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. In particular, please _don't_ format code like this. Instead, paste it into your question, select it, and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K to format it as code. Stack Overflow will indent it by four spaces, making it a [Markdown code block](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode).

Comment: Well, I did it for you... but please format it next time! and like the chris suggested please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: also, in line 19 you have given `Clearance_given` with a small "g" replace with `Clearance_Given ` as per your question to concatenate float or any other type use str() to type cast and then concatenate .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert that into `str` by using `str()` and use `True` and you have typos in your variable names.

```
from time import sleep
#this is a program to run on the HY92 module for the Nanya Rocket
print ("Program initiating")
date_today = "16 December 2016"
print (date_today)
print ('Mission Launch ' + 'Procedure 14.0')
module_name = "string(HY92)"
#the following are numerical variables
A1 = 4
A2 = 28
A3 = 10 #this is a module identifier
A4 = 14 #this is another module identifier
A5 = 39 
A6 = 6
#this is a section which uses the variables defined above
product = (A1 * A2)
quotient = (A4 / A3)
module_math = (product + quotient)
Clearance_Given = True
Clearance_Status = str(Clearance_Given) + str(module_math) + module_name
sleep_time = 1
#print 'Program closing in...'
sleep(sleep_time)
print (5)
sleep(sleep_time)
print (4)
sleep(sleep_time)
print (3)
sleep(sleep_time)
print (2)
sleep(sleep_time)
print (1)
sleep(sleep_time) 
print ("closed")
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help! and i apologize for the formating of the whole question, it's my first time posting here

Answer (score 0):

Python won't execute lines if they're ambiguous.
When you write:

```
a = "Hello" + 2
```

It can't be sure whether you want to add the numeric value of "Hello" with 2 or to add the string value of 2 to "Hello"

In order to solve this you just need to conclusive, In this case:

```
a = "Hello" + str(2)
```

This would cause python to add 2 strings together in order to get "Hello2"